# Cannot set property 'plugin' of undefined: shiner,js

Tags: jquery

I'm having the error: Cannot set property 'plugin' of undefined: shiner.js

```
if ($.inArray(e(d), c) < 0) {
    jQuery.fx.pixelentity.plugin = function () {
        $.pixelentity.plugin.enable = true
    }
}
```

The full code is given here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XStv2/

What can be the cause? I'm using jquery 1.7.1

Another point, the plugin works perfectly on my local machine, but when it is uploaded to the server, this error is pointing out

Comment: It's weird I have the same problem with you, it's working like a charm on local but getting error on server, have you found any solution?

Comment: Im afraid I haven't. There is no documentation with this plugin and its outdated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented on your question I have had the same problem, later I removed these lines,

```
jQuery.fx.pixelentity.plugin = function () {
            $.pixelentity.plugin.enable = true
        }
```

and it works. Yes it's weird but it works.

[here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XStv2/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **wrong order of calling the script** or **conflict**.

1. Add the `jQuery` library
2. Then add your `shiner.js` plugin library.